# Error in onCreateOptionsMenu at detail activity

Tags: android

I have a listview and call detail activity when the item is selected.
My onCreateOptionsMenu has error on displaying the menu at Action Bar.

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
     new MenuInflater(getActivity()).inflate(R.menu.detail_view_menu, menu);
     return (super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu));
 }
```

The error is The method onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu, MenuInflater) in the type Fragment is not applicable for the arguments (Menu). Error happened at return line.
I implement listview and detail activity using fragmentTransaction.
Thanks

Comment: Because your error got solved you might want to choose an answer so others can benefit from your question.

Answer (score 0):

Your onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) just needs to be in the activity that hosts the fragment, not in the fragment itself.

You could also consider extending a BaseActivity and including it in there just once.

```
public class BaseActivity extends Activity {

    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        new MenuInflater(getActivity()).inflate(R.menu.detail_view_menu, menu);
        return (super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu));
    }

}

public class ListActivity extends BaseActivity {
    // ...
}

public class DetailActivity extends BaseActivity {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I have two menus. main_menu.xml is for MainActivity.java menu. main_menu.xml is used when listview is displayed. When detail activity is loaded. I like to replace with detail_view_menu.xml. Where I need to implement for this replacement?

Comment: That's a completely different question.  Solved your original question.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this but put it in your main Activity class:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.detail_view_menu, menu);
    return true;
}
```

**OR** if you want your Fragment to add items to the ActionBar you have to use a slightly different construct:

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
   super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
   inflater.inflate(R.menu.detail_view_menu, menu);
}
```

You have an additional parameter that you have to add(MenuInflater). Also, in a Fragment the onCreateOptionsMenu doesn't return a boolean value.

Now that you have your inflater you need to call `setHasOptionsMenu(true)` in your Fragment's `onCreate()` method. Otherwise your items will not be displayed in the ActionBar.

Your **Fragment** code, handling the **menu inflation**, should now look like this:

```
public class DetailFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
       super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
       inflater.inflate(R.menu.detail_view_menu, menu);
    }
}
```

Comment: Now is no more error. Detail activity is loaded but the menu is still the same previous menu, the new R.menu.detail_view_menu is not reflected yet. I put setHasOptionsMenu(true) inside onCreateView() of the DetailActivity.java

Comment: DetailActivity.java is your Activity or your Fragment?.. Careful, you have to insert the setHasOptionsMenu(true) inside the onCreateView() method that is found in your Fragment class.

Comment: If you would provide more code on how you handle things I might be able to assist you more.

Comment: DetailActivity.java is my fragment and I put setHasOptionsMenu(true) inside DetailActivity.java class. I'll put the code in the new thread

Comment: Actually I have two menus. main_menu.xml is for MainActivity.java menu. main_menu.xml is used when listview is displayed. When detail activity is loaded by tapping an item in the listview, I like to replace with detail_view_menu.xml. This is the menu replacement, is it?

Comment: Please edit your question and add your MainActivity.java and DetailActivity.java relevant code.

Comment: I edited my answer. Add super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater); and see if it works like that.