# Changing the menu when switching one activity to another activity

Tags: android

I like to change menu when the activity is changed. I have MainActivity.java with activity_main.xml menu. Then I have MyDetailFragment.java with detail_view_menu.xml. The MainActivity menu is inflated in the onCreateOptionsMenu of MainActivity.java as

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    new MenuInflater(this).inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return (super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu));
}
```

It works fine. When one of the items is tapped and the  MyDetailFragment.java is loaded, I like to display detail_view_menu.xml. How I implement is

```
public class MyDetailsFragment extends Fragment {


TrackerInfo trackerInfo;
public MyDetailsFragment() {    
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment

    View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_details_fragment, container, false);  
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    TextView displayText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.details); 
    displayText.setText(trackerInfo.getIdnumber());
    return view;
}

public void retrieveData(TrackerInfo tracker){
    trackerInfo = tracker;
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
   inflater.inflate(R.menu.detail_view_menu, menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
       case R.id.track:

            return (true);

       case R.id.view_history:
            return (true);

    }

    return (super.onOptionsItemSelected(item));}}
```

But the problem is that the menu is still the same activity_main menu and never changed. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need to super call the same method.

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
   inflater.inflate(R.menu.detail_view_menu, menu);
   super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}
```

Once I had issue when the new menu items where appended to the menu. So I resolve it with removing all menu items before inflating new ones.
Like this:

```
public static void emptyFragmentOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
        if(menu==null)return;
        for(int i=0; i < menu.size(); i++)
            menu.removeItem(menu.getItem(i).getItemId());
}
```

Cheers,

Edit: How I used the method:

```
 @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
       emptyFragmentOptionsMenu(menu);
       inflater.inflate(R.menu.detail_view_menu, menu);
       super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }
```

Comment: how you can have Menu menu in your argument? I mean how do you create menu object to call your public static void emptyFragmentOptionsMenu(Menu menu).

Answer (score 0):

**First:** you should have an `onCreate()` method above your `onCreateView()` and there you `set setHasOptionsMenu(true);`

**Second:** you need to use `super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);` after the inflater in your `onCreateOptionsMenu()`.

**Third:** you have just duplicated your question that you originally posted **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15594753/error-in-oncreateoptionsmenu-at-detail-activity)**. Please don't do that in the future. I have provided you with additional details on that question then you switched on this one. Next time just edit your original question. Otherwise you might just sabotage yourself and become annoying for those trying to help you.

**Do this**:

```
public class MyDetailsFragment extends Fragment {


TrackerInfo trackerInfo;
public MyDetailsFragment() {    
}

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true); // this should go here not in onCreateView();

        // ....
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment

    View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_details_fragment, container, false);  
    TextView displayText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.details); 
    displayText.setText(trackerInfo.getIdnumber());
    return view;
}

public void retrieveData(TrackerInfo tracker){
    trackerInfo = tracker;
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
   inflater.inflate(R.menu.detail_view_menu, menu);
   super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater); // you need to call super
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
       case R.id.track:

            return (true);

       case R.id.view_history:
            return (true);

    }

    return (super.onOptionsItemSelected(item));
    }
}
```